# Online sources for XAML styles

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, designer, styles

Are there any good online sources of XAML styles? Free or paid, doesn't matter - I'd just like to find a reasonably large collection of styles that I can drop into my application and try out different looks

edit: first google search came up with
http://www.xamltemplates.net/
http://reuxables.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (Silverlight) Toolkit brings a lot of styles with it:
http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/silverlight-toolkit-using-themes-in-silverlight/ 
Here you can find some other application themes: (4 new application themes for Silverlight 4: JetPack, Accent Color, **Windows 7** and Cosmopolitan) 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e9da0eb8-f31b-4490-85b8-92c2f807df9e&displaylang=en